# How can i send registration id getting from GCM in broadcastReceiver to main Activity

Tags: android

I am android developer developing an app.Here I am getting registration id from GCM and saving it in a string, now i want to send this registration id from broadcastreceiver class to my mainActivity class so that I can send this value to my server.I am trying to use intent but force close occur always.

code for GcmBroadcastreceiver.class is

public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {

```
        String action=intent.getAction();
        Log.d("msg", action);

    if(action.equals("com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION"))
        {

            Log.d("msg", "within if loop");

            Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
            if (bundle != null) {
                Set<String> keys = bundle.keySet();
                Iterator<String> it = keys.iterator();
                Log.d("msg","Dumping Intent start");
                while (it.hasNext()) {
                    String key = it.next();
                //    Log.d("msg","[" + key + "=" + bundle.get(key)+"]");
              Toast.makeText(context,("msg"+"[" + key + "=" + bundle.get(key)+"]"), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                Log.d("msg","Dumping Intent end");

            }
            String registrationId=intent.getStringExtra("registration_id");
            Toast.makeText(context, "reg is"+registrationId, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            Intent in=new Intent(context,MainActivity.class);
            in.putExtra("RegID", registrationId);
            context.startActivity(in);
            Toast.makeText(context, "Intent is send to mainactivity class", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();



         //   Log.d("regid", registrationId);
            String error=intent.getStringExtra("error");
            //Log.d("error", error);
            String unregistered=intent.getStringExtra("unregistered");
        //  Log.d("unregistered", unregistered);
        }

        else if(action.equals("com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE"))
        {
            String data1=intent.getStringExtra("data1");
            Log.d("data1::",data1);
            String data2=intent.getStringExtra("data2");
            Log.d("data2::",data2);
        }
```

Comment: please post your logcat

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your Main Activity, create a BroadcastReceiver as:

```
private BroadcastReceiver mReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        //post registration id to server
    }
};
```

Register this receiver in [onCreate](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onCreate%28android.os.Bundle%29) of your activity as:

```
registerReceiver(mReceiver, new IntentFilter("your_package_name.REGISTER_DEVICE"));
```

In [onDestroy()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onDestroy%28%29) of your activity, unregister the receiver:

```
if (mReceiver != null) {
    unregisterReceiver(mReceiver);
}
```

Once you get the registration id, you can send broadcast to you main activity as:

```
context.sendBroadcast(new Intent("your_package_name.REGISTER_DEVICE").putExtra("GCM_REG_ID", registrationId));
```

Or, you can make use of [LocalBroadcastManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/LocalBroadcastManager.html) also;

Answer (score 0):

Simple method which i prefer is register your intent with a activity, set that activity's property launch mode  as single task true in android manifest and handle that intent in activity in on new intent. Now only thing you need do is call that intent from the broadcast receiver, with the contents you want send to activity handle it in activity's on new intent method.

Answer (score 0):

You have to create another broadcast receiver inside you activity and put your data as extras.